# Validating in objective c Password encrypted in Java using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 algorithm

Tags: java, android, objective-c, c, encryption

**Userpath:**
One registered in my android app, then decided to login in through the iphone app.

Server sends me Encrypted Password and I need to compare with the one user have just entered in the password field.

Here is Java method which encrypts the string:

```
public static String encrypt(String password)  {
        int iterations = 1000;
        char[] chars = password.toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = getSalt().getBytes();

        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, iterations, 256);
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] hash = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        return toHex(hash);
}
```

What I have so far:

```
- (BOOL)isPasswordValid 
{   
  NSString * saltString = @"5b42406231323062343030";
  NSString * storedPasswordString = @"90bd42e6f15ccd2d3ec3386d031758898bb7bc08f476a3d7afe6fe1cfbc372e6";

  NSData * hashData = [storedPasswordString dataFromHexString]; 

  unsigned char out[256];

  //converting saltstring into char array
  //
  NSMutableArray * saltArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < saltString.length; idx++) {
   [saltArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [saltString characterAtIndex:idx]]];
  }

  unsigned char * buffer = (unsigned char *)calloc([saltArray count],
                                              sizeof(unsigned char));

  for (int i = 0; i < [saltArray count]; i++)
    buffer[i] = (char)[saltArray objectAtIndex:i];

  PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1("password", strlen("password"), buffer, sizeof(buffer), ITERATION, 256, out);

  NSMutableString * hashTestString = [NSMutableString new];
  for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < sizeof(out); idx++) {
    [hashTestString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", out[idx]]];
  }

  NSData * hashDataTest = [hashTestString dataFromHexString];

  const char *hashBytes = [hashData bytes];
  const char *hashBytesTest = [hashDataTest bytes];

  int diff = hashData.length ^ hashDataTest.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < hashData.length && i < hashDataTest.length; i++) {
    diff |= hashBytes[i] ^ hashBytesTest[i];
  }

  free(buffer);
  return diff == 0;
}
```

[Method PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-12/openssl/crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c) Unfortunately, it always returns -1 for test case.

**THOUGHTS:**

Salt from the received string in hex representation and it might be the problem. So i tried to convert hex `@"5b42406231323062343030"` to string `@"[B@b120b400"`, then converted it to char array, but still no results.

**UPD:**
if I use `unsigned char salt[] =  {'[','B','@','b','1','2','0','b','4','0','0'};' instead of`buffer` variable it works fine. So, my hex string conversion to char array sucks.

Comment: Password validation should all be server side. Comparing the encrypted values of the stored and entered passwords.

Comment: Whatever, I need to encrypt it correctly then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing over and over I made my solution to work. As I commented above,
if I use `unsigned char salt[] =  {'[','B','@','b','1','2','0','b','4','0','0'};` instead of `buffer` variable it works fine. So, I noticed my hex string conversion to char array sucks.

`NSString` instance has `- (const char *)UTF8String` method, which returns a null-terminated UTF8 representation.

Additionally, I converted my hex-salt, which I received from server into NSString and finally come up with following snippet:

```
- (BOOL)isPasswordValid 
{
    NSString * saltString = @"[B@b120b400";
    NSString * storedPasswordString = @"90bd42e6f15ccd2d3ec3386d031758898bb7bc08f476a3d7afe6fe1cfbc372e6";

    NSData * hashData = [storedPasswordString dataFromHexString];

    unsigned char out[[hashData length]];

    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1("password", strlen("password"), 
                          (const unsigned char *)[saltString UTF8String], 
                          strlen([saltString UTF8String]), 1000, 
                                  [hashData length], out);

    NSMutableString * hashTestString = [NSMutableString new];
    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < sizeof(out); idx++) {
      [hashTestString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", out[idx]]];
    }

    NSData * hashDataTest = [hashTestString dataFromHexString];

    const char * hashBytes = [hashData bytes];
    const char * hashBytesTest = [hashDataTest bytes];

    int diff = hashData.length ^ hashDataTest.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < hashData.length && i < hashDataTest.length; i++) {
        diff |= hashBytes[i] ^ hashBytesTest[i];
    }

    return diff == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You reserve space for `buffer` using `calloc`:

```
unsigned char * buffer = (unsigned char *)calloc([saltArray count],
```

Here:

```
PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1("password", strlen("password"), buffer, sizeof(buffer), ..
```

`sizeof(buffer)` returns `sizeof(unsigned char *)`, use `strlen((char *)buffer)`

Comment: *warning: `passing 'unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'const char * converts between pointers to integer types with different types'`

Comment: Yes, there is a warning for the conversion, use a cast: `strlen((char *) buffer)`

Comment: Sorry, I can't compile your code on my machine to check this :(

Comment: if I use `unsigned char salt[] =  {'[','B','@','b','1','2','0','b','4','0','0'};` instead of buffer variable it works fine. So, my hex string conversion to char array sucks.